# Why doesn't the gml 3.1.1 schema validate with xmllint?

Tags: tools, gml, xml

Running xmllint on the gml 3.1.1 schema fails, even though the release notes claim that this release was created to get the schema to validate using 'common tools'.  There's questions about this on the web, but no satisfying answers.

```
xmllint --schema http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd \
        --noout foo.xml
```

returns something like:

> element complexType: Schemas parser error : 
>   local list type: A 
>   type, derived by list or union, must have 
>   the simple ur-type definition as base type

This is not the same problem as the one described [here](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/904), which was a Xerces C++ issue.

<s>If there is some other xmllint issue here, what xml validator is known to work with GML?</s>

I have this problem on a few different flavors of Ubuntu, CentOS, and RHEL 5.x

**Update:**

The 3.1.1 and 2.1.2 GML schemas validate using the following tools:

1. The W3C [XML Schema Validator](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema.html#XSV)
2. Sun's [msv](http://msv.java.net/):

   running `java -jar msv.jar -warning gml\base\gml.xsd`

   returned 1 warning about "anyType" in gmlBase.
3. Using the validator bundled in eclipse worked with no errors or warnings.